# signing with xades4j library

Tags: signing, xades4j

Is there any working example of how to sign using xades4j library? Here's what I want to do:

1. Create an XML document
2. Convert some binary data (PDF or DOC file) to base64
3. Put converted data to the recently created XML document
4. Sign the XML document in Xades-C or Xades-T format.

First three steps are not a big problem. I could not find any useful working example of xades signing (Step 4).

Answer (score 2):

The [xades4j wiki on GitHub](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/wiki/DefiningSignedResources) has the documentation you're looking for. In addition, the unit tests on the library source code include [examples for many scenarios](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/blob/master/src/test/java/xades4j/production/SignerTTest.java).